# How can I loop through every column in pivot table and identify top 2-3 numbers in table?

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet and I want to highlight the top two number values in each column.

I was thinking of something like this

```
Sub like_this()

   Dim rng As Range

   For Each rng In Range(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'highlight top two values in yellow 

   Next rng

End Sub
```

How would I go about looping through the cells in those two columns to find the top two values? I know conditional formatting can do it, but I don't have time to do a separate statement for top 2 in every individual column when I have hundreds of them, that's why I suggested a VBA loop.

Comment: You can do this with conditional formatting

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question so heavily? Question is well explained and the person even provided code showing their attempt to solve the problem. Seems like literally the exact type of question that StackOverflow is meant to help people with!

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero yeah, I'm confused. My problem requires a loop because I want to look at separate columns, not a whole table

Comment: I will help you. I think this can be solved with conditional formatting, even if you have multiple columns. I'll provide an answer and, if it doesn't work for you, then we can try a VBA solution afterwards. No worries! I really don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero - I don't think that code represents an attempt to solve the problem. This is the sort of thing that should be searchable as a common type of problem.

Comment: @SJR I have researched, I couldn't find anything this specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nick, I think you can accomplish this with conditional formatting. Select the ENTIRE table (not the headers though) and then use the formula in the screenshot below. Set up the formula for the TOP LEFT cell in your selection (in the case of my screenshot that's cell A1).

Then, of course, set it to format the fill as yellow.

[image]

Comment: For future readers: If "top two numbers" means the smallest ones, then add a 1 for the order `=RANK(A1,A:A,1)<=2` says [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723)